# Accessing homestead site on another computer in network

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have set up and my wordpress site on homestead. I have windows machine running it and it works nicely, i can access my configured URL when i edit hosts file. Now i want to access the domain from different windows machine that relies in the same network but this time editing hosts file does not work, it simply cant resolve it and times out. Is it even possible to do that? I would prefer if i can get it working with hosts file and not using vagrant share or similar service like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem accessing my homestead  install across the network until I recently discovered I could perform a **Network Preview** for my Prepros projects [(https://prepros.io/)](https://prepros.io/).

Homestead files are mapped to your local computer; adding them to prepros projects will give indirect access to your homestead website.

Its been working quite well for me.